# Control a robot with 2 motors and a H-bridge with Arduino and ROS?

Tags: arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all.

Does any one have a project which makes you connect an arduino to ROS, in order to control a robot with two motors connected to a h-bridge, just as a beginner project to get started?

Thanks, best regards!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211874/control-a-robot-with-2-motors-and-a-h-bridge-with-arduino-and-ros?/) by [Dynamite](https://answers.ros.org/users/22877/dynamite/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-06-22

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rai](https://answers.ros.org/users/29580/rai/) on 2017-03-10**:
hey, did you find a way to it? I need exactly this right now.

**Comment by [Dynamite](https://answers.ros.org/users/22877/dynamite/) on 2017-03-10**:
Hey unfortunately not. I have tried to learn more c/c++ programming meanwhile and maybe I should look into it again.
Any way if you figure it out or find more information please share it here for all to see. Thanks.

**Comment by [Rai](https://answers.ros.org/users/29580/rai/) on 2017-03-10**:
Yeah,I'll make sure to share it here if I come up with something useful, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

see also http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2015-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the [ros_arduino_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_arduino_bridge) package. It does exactly what you want and has reasonable examples.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-06-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [v.leto](https://answers.ros.org/users/37009/v.leto/) on 2019-08-29**:
I have the same problem but I have to use raspberry pi3, so I think that this package is not fine for me, isn't it? It's a univ.ersity project and I am going crazy!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-08-30**:
@v.leto: it sounds like your question is different from the original question here. I'd suggest you ask it as a new question, but it looks like already have, and have some better feedback there: https://answers.ros.org/question/331509/rover-raspberry-pi3l298-h-bridge-and-i2cpwm-library/

**Comment by [v.leto](https://answers.ros.org/users/37009/v.leto/) on 2019-08-30**:
yes, I have written my own question but without succes...